# Como enviar http headers con SOAP::Lite?

Tags: php, soap, perl

Estoy intentado enviar unos parámetros en los http headers para el consumo de un web service, estoy utilizando `SOAP::Lite` pero cuando ingreso la linea
`SOAP::Header->name(campo=> $valor)`
se ingresa dentro de la etiqueta `</header>` de la estructura xml y no funciona el consumo. Como debo enviar estos datos?. En php utilizan `stream_context`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTTP` es el método de transporte para `SOAP` que estas usando, por lo que donde tienes que mirar es alrededor de [`SOAP::Transport`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SOAP-Lite/lib/SOAP/Transport.pod#SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client).

Algo así debería funcionar:

```
my $client = SOAP::Lite->new(proxy => 'http://url.example.com/');
my $transport = $client->transport;
$transport->default_header('CABECERA_HTTP' => 'VALOR');
$client->call(metodo => @parametros);
```

`$client->transport` te va a devolver un objecto [`SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SOAP-Lite/lib/SOAP/Transport.pod#SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client) que hereda de [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent). Ahí tienes los métodos para manipular headers, cookies y demás.